# iOS validation got Main_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc was not found

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am trying to distribute my iOS app, and I got the following error message during xCode validation. 
"storyboard file 'Main_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc' was not found please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename". Need some advices...

Comment: just use name "Main_iPhone" don't include .storyboard in the string u provide for storyboard name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by going to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy bundle resources, and add the Main_iPhone.storyboard file.

Comment: Not a right solution. one dont want to add iphone storyboard to the iPad project.

Answer (score 31):

Remove the storyboard from the plist file if you use iPad

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

or if you use iPhone

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

Comment: please elaborate on this answer

Comment: You have to go to your plist file and remove the storyboard that are not used in your project.. If you have iphone application remove the ipad storyboard... if you have ipad remove iphone storyboard

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. To elaborate further, you must view your -Info.plist file as source XML rather as a plist file and then delete the noted lines below from the file entirely.

Comment: For those still confused (I was), you need to find your app's plist file (usually 'AppName-Info.plist') in the xcode file browser, reveal it in the Finder, and then open it as a text file to make these changes.  That fixed things for me.

Comment: This answer helped me in a situation where I had originally created a universal app, but later wanted to make it iPhone-only. The iPad storyboard reference was left in the .plist file after I deleted the actual storyboard file from the project. That is why I also got the "missing .storyboardc file" error when validating the archive for iTunes Connect. This really should be caught at build time by Xcode!

Comment: Perfect! Saved my bacon!

Comment: Saved life and hours of research. Thanks a lot for short and sweet answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the exact name of the storyboard according to apple guidelines default name is :- Main_iPhone.storyboard but i think you can change the name of the storyboard default to 'Main_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc' but they find the default name of storyboard in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this helped me too.

I modified the ProgramFile-Info.plist under the Supporting Files folder. I found two columns with Main storyboard file base name. I deleted the iPad one that I was getting the error on and then I was able to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Using xCode 6.0.1 I got this error. None of the other solutions listed here fixed it. I resolved it by deleting the storyboard in question from the project (Removing references only -- not moving to trash), then putting it back in via Add Files.

Answer (score 1):

In your Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources make sure your main storyboard is included. For example main.storyboard. It will show up red. Some people think that because it's red it should be deleted. But without it, you will get this error when you try to submit to iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you accidentally deleted a storyboard file. In my case, I solved this like by creating a new storyboard file with a different name. Then copy paste all controllers from Main_iPhone~iphone to this and edit the plist and other places with the new file name. This will work

Answer (score 0):

Editing the plist file solved it for me.

- Go to Targets -> Info
- To delete a field, hover over the up/down arrow icon next to the key you want to delete, and press the minus.
- Or, if you need to add a field, hover over any up/down icon and press the plus.

I had a bug where it was looking for an iPad storyboard, even though I was only targeting iPhones.  I simply had to delete the corresponding key/value pair from here.