# MainStoryboard_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc was not found error when archiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, app-store-connect, archive

When archiving an iPad only application that was developed in Xcode 4.6 within Xcode 5 using an iOS 6.1 target and SDK, I'm receiving the error below stating that the MainStoryboard_iPhone~iphone.storyboardc was not found.

It should not say this, as I ONLY have iPad checked off as a supported device under the project settings. I'm unsure of how to precede as I am unable to archive and push up my application to the app store as the validation check failed.

Does anyone have a fix for this?
I have already updated the bundle for Xcode 5 settings and I've updated/reverted the storyboards to Xcode 4.6.

[image]

Comment: This link might help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873058/ios-validation-got-main-iphoneiphone-storyboardc-was-not-found

Comment: I'm posting the question again because non of the current answers in stack overflow have been helpful, you can see me responding in some of those posts requesting for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I had to open the info.plist file for the project as source XML rather a plist, and delete

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

from the file. Once this was done, everything disappeared.